# Append a sumproduct at the end of an existing formula for each cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

SUPPOSE cell G1 in my worksheet has this formula 
=$R$5*I4+$S$5*H4+$T$5*G4+$U$5*F4+$V$5*E4+$W$5*D4+$X$5*C4+$Y$5*B4

G2 has a existing different formula
=$R$5*I4+$S$5*H4+$T$5*G4+$U$5*F4

now to this existing formula i want to add a new sum product $X$5*A4
to make the new formula of G1 like this

=$R$5*I4+$S$5*H4+$T$5*G4+$U$5*F4+$V$5*E4+$W$5*D4+$X$5*C4+$Y$5*B4+**$X$5*A4**

and that of G2 like this
=$R$5*I4+$S$5*H4+$T$5*G4+$U$5*F4+**$X$5*A5**

the initial formula in all the cells is different, so that's why i am thinking of writing a macro. Please help me

I have made this code looking at the comments:

```
        Sub test2()

        Dim myRange As Range, Cell As Range
        Dim targetsheet As Worksheet
        Set targetsheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim abc As String


        For i = 1 To 14
         abc = "R7" & "C" & (i + 24)
            With targetsheet
            Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(77, i + 2), .Cells(87, i + 15))
            End With
        '    MsgBox myRange
            For Each Cell In myRange
                If IsEmpty(Cell) Then
                'MsgBox ("=" & abc & "*R[-75]C[" & (-i + 1) & "]")

                    Cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & abc & "*R[-75]C[" & (-i + 1) & 
                       "]"
                Else
                    Cell = Cell.FormulaR1C1 & "+" & abc & "]*R[-75]C[" & (-i 
                  + 1) & "]"
                End If
            Next Cell
        Next i

        End Sub
```

now, this code is working well for i =1 but as soon as i turns 2 ; 
the value of Cell.FormulaR1C1 becomes **R7C25*R[-75]C** please help me correct this. THANKS

Comment: why u don't use `sumproduct` function ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please specify what is the formula on first cell, second third...and when you add `+$X$5*A4`

Comment: In your loop you are writing to 13 columns, on your next loop you are overwriting 12 of them, likewise in each consecutive loop, is this intentional?

Comment: Also you have a leading `]` in your `else` statement that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can get and set a cell formula with `.Formula`, for example

```
Dim myCell As Range
Set myCell = Range("A1")
myCell = myCell.Formula & "+$X$5*A4"
```

I guess in your situation you would set the range to be where all your cells are and loop through them appending this ending, but this isn't a code for me site so have a play and post a new question if you get stuck.

**EDIT**

As per your question updates, you can still use this approach by looping through each cell and using the `R1C1` formulas.

```
Sub test()

Dim myRange As Range, Cell As Range
Set myRange = Range("G1:J8")

For Each Cell In myRange
    Cell = Cell.FormulaR1C1 & "+R5C24*R[4]C[-6]"
Next Cell

End Sub
```

`R5C24` is an absolute reference to cell `$X$5`, whereas `R[4]C[-6]` is your relative path from the current cell.

Comment: I used this macro 
Sub abc_test()
Dim myCell As Range
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Set myCell = Range("G1:J8")
myCell = myCell.Formula & "+$X$5*A4"
End Sub
But it is showing run time error 13.

Comment: If you want a dynamic reference on `A4` this routine won't work.

Comment: @Pspl is correct. Update your question with more information to get better answers.

Comment: @rag this is the right approach. All _you_ need to do is build the string to append in a loop

Comment: @Tim Wilkinson, of course! Actually I just posted my answer to give a solution without using VBA. But, honesty, I would use VBA myself...

Comment: @TimWilkinson please have a look,

Answer (score 0):

Since you can add `$X$5*A4` on the beginning of the formula, why don't you use the `replace` tool available on Excel? Simply replace `=` by `=$X$5*A4+` on all cells.

If you want a dynamic reference to `A4` and the first cell you want to change is `G1` (the cells that's actually referred to `A4`), replace instead by `=$X$5*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+3;COLUMN()-6))+`.

Comment: I want dynamic reference on A4 not absolute.

Comment: What's the address of the first cell you want to change?

Comment: please have a look at the question